# Как передать данные из мобильного приложения в Telegram Bot / Django сайт?

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, kivy, django-rest-framework

Помогите, пожалуйста, начинающему разобраться)

Есть программа, написанная под Android, которая генерирует текстовые данные.
Меня интересует, каким образом можно реализовать передачу этих данных в телеграм бота на другом мобильном устройстве?

Я не могу разобраться какую БД для этого использовать? И возможно ли вообще это сделать, так как в сети, о связке Kivy App-БД-Telegram Bot, ничего нету.

Может лучше использовать Django REST, для такой цели, тогда пользователь сможет просмотреть данные на сайте?

Извините за глупые вопросы, спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае мобильное приложение выступает в роли клиента и хранить в нём ничего нельзя. Это приложение должно взаимодействовать с сервером (бэкэндом), например, на том же Django. Далее, эти данные уже можно различными способами запрашивать на стороне телеграм-бота.
Первый вариант такой - бэкэнд приложение, написанное на Django для обслуживания мобильного приложения будет совмещено с телеграм-ботом, то есть, иметь одну базу данных и запускаться в разных потоках. Это более простой и прямой путь. Будет использована одна база данных для обоих приложений, более подойдёт для маленьких или учебных проектов.
Второй вариант - разделить приложения, веб-сервер отдельно, а телеграм-бот отдельно, тогда на стороне бота нужно будет запрашивать данные у сервера мобильного приложения. Это более сложный подход, будут использоваться разные базы данных и разные приложения, нужно писать дополнительный API для взаимодействия между сервисами. Он более правильным будет для больших проектов.

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ! Посоветуйте, какую БД использовать для такой цели?(первый вариант)

Comment: @BondarMisha, Отлично подойдёт любая SQL СУБД, например, PostgreSQL

Comment: Понял, еще раз, спасибо)